# How to properly add template tags to a django project

Tags: python, django, gentelella

I am playing with [django-gentelella](https://github.com/GiriB/django-gentelella) and try to add custom template tags to the project.

According to the latest Django documentation, one should add a "templatetags" directory, at the same level as models.py, views.py, etc. Also, an **init**.py file should be placed in the directory.

I added my template tags into a file called "template_tags.py" and restarted the server. In my templates, I load the file using "{% load template_tags %}" at the top of the file.

Unfortunately, this does not work yet. According to the Django documentation, it is also required to add the template_filters to the INSTALLED APPS.

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to get the right path in dot notation. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You don't add the template tags to INSTALLED_APPS, you add the app they are in. There shouldn't be any dotted path involved.

Answer (score 2):

**/profiles/templatetags/custom_tags.py**

```
@register.filter(name='getLocalTimeDifference')
def getLocalTimeDifference(value):
    value = value.replace(..)
    return value
```

**/profiles/templates/navbar.html**

```
{% load custom_tags %}
...

<div class="notification-meta">
    <small class="timestamp">{{ notification.timesince | getLocalTimeDifference}} before </small>
</div>
```

P.S. __init_.py should also be added to templatetags directory

Comment: I tried that and now I get: 'template_tags' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_static
admin_urls
cache
i18n
l10n
log
static
staticfiles
tz

Comment: is name of your python file 'template_tags.py' ?

Comment: Yes it is. Really strange.